# Starting with Email-ext plug-in

Tags: email-ext

problems using Email-ext

1. using groovy/jelly script(Default)
2. Fail to send emails
3. attachment pattern doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution to above problems:

1.create a new job in jenkins and make a note of your job workspace plays an important role.
Email-ext comes with some ready made default scripts which we can use to send emails with attachments.
place the scriptname you are using inside defalut contents use the pattern below

`{script,template="nameofthetemplate}`

2.make a note that there are no commiters option in this plug-in infact use triggers and send emails to recipents list by selecting one of the options a.developers b.culprits c.recipentslist d.requestors

3.This is the critical point because attachment section in jenkins use Ant script.so Ant script work mainly on realtive addressing rather than absolute addressing.
so content in attachment pattern should be some thing like this

`**/foldername/*.txt`

(anyextension)
Note:make sure the floder exists in your job workspace

Hope this helps to some extent

Comment: Just as a comment, you need to use ${SCRIPT,template="nameofthetemplate"} the case is important.